# Triple every element of an array with recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I've been practicing recursion, trying to get more comfortable with it, but this one problem keeps bugging me.
I'm supposed to write a recursive program that triples each element of an array. At first, it seemed simple enough.

```
public static void triple (int[] a, int index) {
    if (index < a.length()) {
        a[index]*=3;
        triple(a, index + 1);
    }
}
```

But when I looked at the problem again, I realized that I'd made a mistake. The parameters for the method are only supposed to be an integer array with no index.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: I think they intend for you to write a helper method and call that from the one-argument method.

Comment: If you're going to practice with recursion, you should choose problems that are recursive in nature. Do not use recursion for its own sake where it is not appropriate.  This is like buying a new chain-saw and deciding to carve the turkey with it.  Recursion can be extremely powerful but it is not appropriate in many situations.

Comment: Miam turkey ;) Anyway, you can always return the index instead of passing it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not the best problem to be solved with  recursion.

Leave the method as it is (replace `length()` with `length` only).
Overload it with another method:

```
public static void triple(int[] a) {
    triple(a, 0);
}
```

Then in your code you can go for:

```
int[] t = {1, 2, 3};
triple(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: this problem can't be really solved using recursion - assuming that you **only** can pass down the array itself.

The point is: you have to somehow know which indexes have been tripled; and which not.

In other words: you somehow have to cheat; you would have to keep some helper variable somewhere that tells you about the last processed index; or something alike.

But as said; that would mean to implement a solution ... that can only work by "massaging" the requirements.

Meaning: when you really restrict yourself to **one** method that takes just the array as argument, then you can't solve this puzzle!